# `load': no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm newbie on *ruby on rails* and I'm trying to test my controller with respect on *ruby on rails*.
It worked before, but now I don't know what happened, but when I do the test, I got the next error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load': no such file to load -- /Users/armandodejesussantoyareales/Documents/project_newbie/Estaciones/estaciones/spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

this is my spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserController do

it "create new user" do
    get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com', :name => 'userexample'     }
    flash[:notice] = 'new user was successfully created.'
end
  describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
  end
end
```

and this is my `Usercontroller`

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_session_path
    else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to @user
end
end
```

Comment: Nothing directly to do with your question, but you will likely have problems using a singular name for a Rails controller. By convention, this should be called `UsersController`, and the file name should be users_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/Users/armandodejesussantoyareales/Documents/project_newbie/Estaciones/estaciones/spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb
```

Are you sure that's the right path? In a terminal, what happens when you do type in:

```
ls /Users/armandodejesussantoyareales/Documents/project_newbie/Estaciones/estaciones/spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb
```

If you get an error saying `No such file or directory`, then that path doesn't exist. If it just echoes back the path, then it's fine.

Alternatively, you can just manually look for this file and verify the path. But either way, my guess is you are just entering the path to your spec file incorrectly.